# How to make my snake longer for my snake game on the raspberry pi SenseHat

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am making a snake game on the SenseHat and the website i am learning from tells me that i need to use the mod operator in order to make my snake grow longer every time it eats a food. But my snake just starts growing for ever even though it did not eat anything

the following is the website that i have been using (the link sends you directly to the part that i am stuck on): 
https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/slug/9

Although i have been looking at this for a while, i have no idea where and how i need to put this in my script

This is my entire script for the game.

```
import random
from random import randint
import time
from sense_hat import SenseHat
sense = SenseHat()


vegetables = []
direction = "right"
colx = randint(0,255)
coly = randint(0,255)
colz = randint(0,255)
food_col = (colx, coly, colz)
blank = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)
snake =[ [2,4], [3,4], [4,4] ]
score = (0)

def move():
  global score
  last = snake[-1]
  first = snake[0]
  next = list(last)     
  remove = True

  if direction == "right":
    if last[0] + 1 == 8:
     next[0] = 0
    else:
     next[0] = last[0] + 1

  elif direction == "left":
    if last[0] - 1 == -1: 
      next[0] = 7
    else:
      next[0] = last[0] - 1

  elif direction == "down":
    if last[1] + 1 == 8: 
      next[1] = 0
    else:
      next[1] = last[1] + 1

  elif direction == "up":
    if last[1] - 1 == -1: 
      next[1] = 7
    else: 
      next[1] = last[1] - 1

  if next in vegetables:
    vegetables.remove(next)
    score == 1

  if next in vegetables:
    if remove == True:
      sense.set_pixel(first[0], first[1], blank)
      snake.remove(first)
    if score % 5 == 0:
      remove = False
  snake.append(next)
  sense.set_pixel(next[0], next[1], green)
def draw_snake():
  for segment in snake: 
    sense.set_pixel(segment[0], segment[1], green)

def joystick_moved(event):
  global direction
  direction = event.direction

def make_food():
  new = snake[0]
  while new in snake:
    x = randint(0,7)
    y = randint(0,7)
    new = [x,y]
    for segment in new: 
      sense.set_pixel(x, y, food_col)
  vegetables.append(new)



sense.clear()
draw_snake()
while True: 
  if len(vegetables) < 3: 
    make_food()
  move()
  time.sleep(0.5)
  sense.stick.direction_any = joystick_moved
```

I am wanting to make it so that my snake will grow every time it eats a food but instead it just grows forever from the beginning. Here is a emulator if you want to try my script on a sense hat 
https://trinket.io/sense-hat

Thank You

Comment: think about it as you want to append an element to a list once on a specific event. try to simplify your problem to such case and grow from it.

Answer (score 1):

`snake.append(next)` in `move` is not in a condition. Also you have two `if next in vegetables` conditions and the first removes it from the list which means the second will always be false. You probably want to merge the two.

Comment: what do you mean by snake.append(next) is not a condition?

Comment: You want to do snake.append(next) when the snake grows, your snake.append(next) is currently after the condition that checks if the snake should grow, not in it. You need to indent it so that it only executes when the condition is true.

Comment: when i indent the snake.append(next) so that it is under remove = False or if remove == True: the snake does not move

Comment: Did you merge the two `if next in vegetables:` ? The first one makes it impossible for the second to run.

Comment: yes. i merged the two if next in vegetables: Am i also supposed to indent the sense.set_pixel(next[0], next[1], green)?

Comment: Yes, this line also needs to be in the condition.